# How can I create an image file from bitmapsource C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have tried as follows

```
BitmapSource bitmap;
            bitmap = graphData.CreateScreenshot();
            JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            BitmapFrame outputFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
            encoder.Frames.Add(outputFrame);
            encoder.QualityLevel = 100;
            FileStream stream = new FileStream("test.jpg", FileMode.Create);
            encoder.Save(stream);
```

but I am not able to view the image. I can see following message:

> Windows photo viewer can't open this picture because the picture is being edited in another program

What went wrong here?

Comment: tried stream.close() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try and Close the stream after you've created it using

```
stream.Close();
```

---

That said, it would be better to create the Stream in a `using` statement. The Stream would be disposed of when execution leaves the `using` block and would hence be closed automatically.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("test.jpg", FileMode.Create))
{
    encoder.Save(stream);
}
```

Comment: Looks like people beat me too it in the comments

Comment: Have a look at the Using statement https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx also if it's working now mark as answered. Glad to help.

Comment: its ok I will let you take this one :)

Comment: Muds, Sorry I genuinely was writing this as you commented I had to build a project to double check. :<

Comment: Small advice: put it in a `using` pattern to make it more readable and to prevent issues like this.